# Slick way to check that a diagram is a pullback square (Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, Chapter 2, Proposition 1)

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

I'm reading Chapter 2 of Mac Lane and Moerdijk's *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*.

At some point our guys claim that given a topological space $ X $ and a sheaf $ F $ on $ X $, a subsheaf $ S $ of $ F $ is itself a sheaf if and only if for every open set $ U\subset X $ and every open cover $ U = \bigcup_{i\in I}U_i $ of $ U $, chosen a $ s\in FU $ we have $ s\in SU $ if and only if $ s{\restriction_{U_i}}\in S(U_i) $ for every $ i\in I $.

In the proof it is light-heartedly claimed that the condition $ s\in S(U) $ if and only if $ s{\restriction_{U_i}}\in S(U_i) $ for every $ i\in I $ is equivalent to the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
SU @>>> \prod_\nolimits{i\in I}S(U_i)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
FU @>>> \prod_\nolimits{i\in I}F(U_i)
\end{CD}
$$
being a pullback square, where the horizontal arrows maps $ s\mapsto (s{\restriction}_{U_i})_{i\in I} $ and the vertical arrows are the inclusions.

Is there a "slick" way to prove this fact?

I can show that the condition mentioned above is equivalent to the obvious map
$$
SU\to FU\times_{\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)}\prod_{i\in I}S(U_i) = \left\{(s,(s_i)_{i\in I})\in FU\times \prod_{i\in I}S(U_i) : \text{$ s{\restriction_{U_i}} = s_i $ for every $ i\in I $}\right\},\quad s\mapsto (s,(s{\restriction_{U_i}})_{i\in I})
$$
being a bijection, and that this fact is equivalent to the diagram above being a pullback. But I was wondering if there was a smarter way to prove this fact than exhibiting the bijection above (maybe a trick usign generalized elements, or some other categorical wizardry).

Indeed I'm always at unease when someone asks me to show that a diagram [of sets] is a pullback, and I usually resort to the bijection trick described above, but I find it a little clumsy.

Answer (score 2):

I mean there is nothing wrong or clumsy about using the explicit formula of pullbacks of sets, but if you insist on having a more abstract proof, the following might work.

Recall that $F$ respectively $S$ is a sheaf iff the diagram
$$S(U) \rightarrow \prod_i S(U_i) \overset{\rightarrow}{\underset{\rightarrow}{}} \prod_{i,j} S(U_i \cap U_j)$$
is an equalizer diagram. A monomorphism of functors $S \rightarrow F$ gives rise to a diagram of (wannabe) equalizers
$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
S(U) & \rightarrow & \prod_i S(U_i) & \overset{\rightarrow}{\underset{\rightarrow}{}} & \prod_{i,j} S(U_i\cap U_j)\\
\downarrow &&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
F(U) & \rightarrow & \prod_i F(U_i) & \overset{\rightarrow}{\underset{\rightarrow}{}} & \prod_{i,j} F(U_i\cap U_j)
\end{array}$$
with all vertical morphisms being monic. You can now show explicitly that giving a cone over the left square is the same as giving a cone over the upper equalizer diagram. Thus being universal for one type of these amounts to being universal for the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think the next step in the proof provided by the book consists exactly in noticing what you write in the last paragraph. By the way I was more wandering if the existence and uniqueness conditions in the universal characterization of a pullback correspond in some way to the 1-1nnes and surjectiveness condition on the map $  SU\to FU\times_{\prod_{i\in I}F(U_i)}\prod_{i\in I}S(U_i) $.

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to accept, if it answered your question. Unfortunately I could not quite follow the rest of your comment. It is always the case that a cone $L$ over a cospan $X\rightarrow Y \leftarrow Z$ is a pullback, if and only if the induced map $\ell:L \rightarrow X\times_Y Z$ is an isomorphism. If you didn't know this, it is again a nice exercise. One direction is easy, since if $L$ is a pullback, it is unique up to unique iso. Conversely you can explicitly show the universal property of $L$ by using that of $X\times_Y Z$ and composing with the inverse of $\ell$.

Comment: Yeah I know this fact. I'll better explain why I posted this question. Reading Mac Lane & Moerdijk's book I found myself multiple times wondering what enables the authors to "see" immediately that this or that property can be expressed by saying that some diagram is a pullback diagram. I thought that maybe I was missing something, and that maybe the property of "being a pullback" has an easier characterization or something like that, at least when working in the category of sets. So you're probably right if you think that my question is not well posed:)

Comment: MacLane and Moerdijk are founding fathers of category theory. Of cause they easily see things that others might not. If you work on something for some time, you will be able to see things more easily as well. To explicitly answer your question: No you didn't miss some secret characterization of pullbacks of sets. I guess the intuition should always be that pullbacks are intersections, so if you meditate a bit on it the square in your question really has to be a pullback. It says that $S(U)$ is given by all those sections in $F(U)$ which are obtained by gluing things from the $S(U_i)$s.

Comment: Indeed, I just noticed that if $ A\xrightarrow{f} B\xleftarrow{g} B^\prime $ is a cospan of sets and $ g $ is a mono, then $ f^{-1}(g(A)) $ with the obvious mappings to $ B^\prime $ and $ A $ is a pullback. This helped a lot!